# Multiple Fields Where Keys In Document Vary Average Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I got dataset as follow :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592d4f43d69b643ac0cb9148"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-03-01T16:58:00.000Z"),
    "Technique-Meteo_Direction moyenne du vent_Mean value wind direction[]" : 0.0,
   "Technique-Meteo_Précipitations_Precipitation status[]" : 0.0,
    "Technique-Meteo_Direction du vent_Wind direction[]" : 0.0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592d4f43d69b643ac0cb9149"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-03-01T17:09:00.000Z"),
    "Technique-Meteo_Direction moyenne du vent_Mean value wind direction[]" : 0.0,
    "Technique-Meteo_Précipitations_Precipitation status[]" : 0.0,
   "Technique-Meteo_Direction du vent_Wind direction[]" : 0.0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592d3a6cd69b643ac0cae395"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-30T09:31:00.000Z"),
    "Technique-Electrique_Prises de Courant_Power1[W]" : 14.0,
    "Technique-Electrique_Eclairage_Power2[W]" : 360.0,
    "Technique-Electrique_Electroménager_Power3[W]" : 0.0,
    "Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]" : 14.0,
    "Technique-Electrique_VMC Unelvent_Power5[W]" : 8.0
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592d3a6cd69b643ac0cae396"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-01-30T09:32:00.000Z"),
    "Technique-Electrique_Prises de Courant_Power1[W]" : 15.0,
    "Technique-Electrique_Eclairage_Power2[W]" : 365.0,
    "Technique-Electrique_Electroménager_Power3[W]" : 0.0,
    "Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]" : 14.0,
    "Technique-Electrique_VMC Unelvent_Power5[W]" : 8.0
}
```

There are an "_id", a "timestamp" and multiple sensors fields. The number of sensor is not consistent. With an interface, I chose numerous sensors which I want to include in my query. This choice is stored in a list where each item is the name of the sensor.

example :

```
self.chosenSensors = ["Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]", "Technique-Electrique_VMC Unelvent_Power5[W]"]
```

I would like to calculate the average of values of each chosen sensor. I already did it but I do a query for each sensor.

In the following example, I show you that. (Don't consider the date aggregation, it is the next step)

```
page2.currentColl].aggregate([{"$match":{chosenSensor:{"$exists": True}}}, {"$group":{"_id":{"year":{"$year":"$timestamp"}, "month":{"$month":"$timestamp"}}, "average":{"$avg": chosenSensorAverage}}}])
```

Result (each average is in a new document):

```
RDC-ChambreEnfants_CO2_GAS_CONCENTRATION[ppm]
{'_id': {'year': 2017, 'month': 4}, 'average': 1475.3685814315352}
{'_id': {'year': 2017, 'month': 3}, 'average': 1374.3771154414906}
RDC-ChambreEnfants_Humidité_HUMIDITY[%]
{'_id': {'year': 2017, 'month': 4}, 'average': 37.55591753379364}
{'_id': {'year': 2017, 'month': 3}, 'average': 37.459350662153724}
```

What I would like to get is the following :

```
{
    "Avg_Technique-Meteo_Direction moyenne du vent_Mean value wind direction[]" : 0.0,
    "Avg_Technique-Meteo_Précipitations_Precipitation status[]" : 0.0,
    "Avg_Technique-Meteo_Direction du vent_Wind direction[]" : 0.0
    "Avg_Technique-Electrique_Prises de Courant_Power1[W]" : 14.5,
    "Avg_Technique-Electrique_Eclairage_Power2[W]" : 362.5,
    "Avg_Technique-Electrique_Electroménager_Power3[W]" : 0.0,
    "Avg_Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]" : 14.0,
    "Avg_Technique-Electrique_VMC Unelvent_Power5[W]" : 8.0
}
```

I've been given a hint which is (By Neil Lunn) :

> You could possibly make the statement longer and get the "counts" and
>   "sums" for each using $ifNull to determine when to increment. Then you
>   would $divide "after" the $group pipeline stage to get the final
>   "average".
>
> As noted, the "key names" seem the larger problem to me and would
>   probably be better handled by moving them to "values" within elements
>   of an array

The first problem for me is that I don't know how to use my sensors list in the query. Other problems will probably come after this one is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Outline of Concept

What I was basically saying in the very brief comment is that **instead** for issuing a separate aggregation query for every sensor "key" name, you can put it in **ONE**, as long as you calculate the "averages" correctly.

Of course the problem in your data is that the "keys" are not present in all documents. So to get the correct "average", we cannot just use [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) since it would count "ALL" documents, whether the key was present or not.

So instead we break up the "math", and do a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) for the Total `Count` and total `Sum` of each key first. This uses [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to test for the presence of the field, and also [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to alternate values to return.

```
.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$or": [
      { "Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]": { "$exists": True } },
      { "Technique-Electrique_VMC Unelvent_Power5[W]": { "$exists": True } }
    ]
  }}
  { "$group":{
    "_id":{
      "year":{ "$year":"$timestamp" },
      "month":{ "$month":"$timestamp" }
    },
    "Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]-Sum": { 
      "$sum": { 
        "$ifNull": [ "$Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]", 0 ]
      }
    },
    "Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]-Count": { 
      "$sum": { 
        "$cond": [
          { "$ifNull": [ "$Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]", false ] },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    },
    "Technique-Electrique_VMC Unelvent_Power5[W]-Sum": {
      "$sum": { 
        "$ifNull": [ "$Technique-Electrique_VMC Unelvent_Power5[W]", 0 ]
      }
    },
    "Technique-Electrique_VMC Unelvent_Power5[W]-Count": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [ 
          { "$ifNull": [ "$Technique-Electrique_VMC Unelvent_Power5[W]", false ] },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]-Avg": {
      "$divide": [
        "$Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]-Sum",
        "$Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]-Count"
      ]
    },
    "Technique-Electrique_VMC Unelvent_Power5[W]-Avg": {
      "$divide": [
        "Technique-Electrique_VMC Unelvent_Power5[W]-Sum",
        "Technique-Electrique_VMC Unelvent_Power5[W]-Count"
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

The [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator is a "ternary" operator which means where the first "if" condition is `true`, "then" the second argument is returned, "else" the third argument is returned.

So the point of the ternary in the `"Count"` is to work out:

- If the field is there then return 1 for count
- Otherwise return 0 when it is not there

After the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is done, in order to get the `Average` we use [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) on the two numbers produced for each key within a separate [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage.

The end result is the "average" for every key that you supply, and this considered only adding values and counts for documents where the field was actually present.

So putting all the keys in the one aggregation statement will save you a lot of time and resources on processing.

---

### Dynamic Generation of Pipeline

So to do this "dynamically" in python, start with the list:

```
sensors = ["Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]", "Technique-Electrique_VMC Unelvent_Power5[W]"]

match = { '$match': { '$or': map(lambda x: { x: { '$exists': True } },sensors) } }

group = { '$group': { 
  '_id': {
    'year': { '$year': '$timestamp' },
    'month': { '$month':'$timestamp' }
  }
}}

project = { '$project': {  } }

for k in sensors:
  group['$group'][k + '-Sum'] = {
    '$sum': { '$ifNull': [ '$' + k, 0 ] }
  }
  group['$group'][k + '-Count'] = {
    '$sum': { '$cond': [ { '$ifNull': [ '$' + k, False ] }, 1, 0 ]  }
  }
  project['$project'][k + '-Avg'] = {
    '$divide': [ '$' + k + '-Sum', '$' + k + '-Count' ]
  }

pipeline = [match,group,project]
```

Which generates the same as the full listing above for a given list of "sensors".

Comment: You probably answer a lot of my future questions with that answer. However, my current problem is that my list of sensors can change. This is why I put their name in a list. But I would like to use this list to do what you did. For exemple "$Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]" would be replaced by mySensorsList[0] which is of course impossible in query. I found some use of $in and $unwind but I don't even know if they are the good operators to use and I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @Clément An aggregation pipeline as with all MongoDB queries, is just simply made up from native data structures of the laguage you are using. So these are just `Dicts`. You can construct dictionaries in code, so you don't need to "hardcode" the keys. I'm just showing you how the eventual keynames for the pipeline need to be constructed for the logic here. Understand now? This is a **NOW** thing to do. For "future" I think there is something else you can do to optimize.

Comment: @Clément Since you don't seem to understand, I've written the python code for you to generate the pipeline from a given list of sensors. Throw as many sensor names as you want at it. That's the whole point of doing it dynamically and throwing all the keys at the one aggregation statement.

Comment: Ok, I just saw your Dynamic Generation edit. Actually I was stucked because I didn't know we could include python loop directly in queries. I definitly have a lack of knowledge and logic about this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have just noticed something wrond in my results. Every '<sensor>-Count' takes the last value calculated ; that is to say the count for the last element of sensors. This is really weird because it's not the sum behavior which is almost similar.

Comment: @Clément That is not the `$sum` behavior at all. I suggest there is something different in your own implementation. If you have a sample that you can reproduce a result from then please post by [Asking a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) where I or someone else can look at the detail.