# Count of existing values for each field of a collection, strange behavior

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am trying to get the count of existing values for some fields in a document in order to calculate an average of these values for each year of data. Since we noticed ([in previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717343/multiple-fields-where-keys-in-document-vary-average-aggregation)) that we could not use the $avg aggregation for my case we decided to use a sum/count operation.

Here is a data sample :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593ab6021ccb9b0c0fb226fd"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-17T12:36:00.000Z"),
    "CO2_CEL_SE_I_001" : 1210,
    "CO2_BUR_NE_I_001" : 880
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593ab6021ccb9b0c0fb226fe"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-17T12:37:00.000Z"),
    "CO2_CEL_SE_I_001" : 1210,
    "CO2_BUR_NE_I_001" : 880
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593ab6021ccb9b0c0fb226ff"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-17T12:38:00.000Z"),
    "CO2_CEL_SE_I_001" : 1210,
    "CO2_BUR_NE_I_001" : 880
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593ab63a1ccb9b0c0fb3d3e5"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-02-01T19:26:00.000Z"),
    "CO2_CEL_SE_I_001" : 1080
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593ab6021ccb9b0c0fb22700"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-17T12:39:00.000Z"),
    "CO2_CEL_SE_I_001" : 1210,
    "CO2_BUR_NE_I_001" : 880
}
```

However, obtained results seem not to be what I expected to get. Just below is my query :

```
match = {'$match':{'$or':list(map(lambda x:{x:{'$exists': True}}, chosenSensors))}}

group = {'$group':{'_id':{'year':{'$year':'$timestamp'}}}}

 project = {'$project':{}}

for chosenSensor in chosenSensors:
    group['$group'][chosenSensor+'-Count'] = {'$sum':{'$cond':[{'$ifNull':[True, False]}, 1, 0]}}
    group['$group'][chosenSensor+'-Sum'] = {'$sum':{'$ifNull':['$'+chosenSensor, 0]}}
    project['$project'][chosenSensor+'-Avg'] = {'$divide':['$'+chosenSensor+'-Sum', '$'+chosenSensor+'-Count']}
    project['$project'][chosenSensor+'-Count'] = True
    project['$project'][chosenSensor+'-Sum'] = True

sort = {'$sort': {"_id":1}}

pipeline = [match, group, project, sort]

for doc in client["cleanData"]["maison2"].aggregate(pipeline):
print(doc)
```

---

And here are my results :

**chosenSensors = ["CO2_BUR_NE_I_001", "CO2_CEL_SE_I_001"]**

```
{'_id': {'year': 2016}, 'CO2_BUR_NE_I_001-Count': 5, 'CO2_BUR_NE_I_001-Sum': 3520, 'CO2_CEL_SE_I_001-Count': 5, 'CO2_CEL_SE_I_001-Sum': 5920, 'CO2_BUR_NE_I_001-Avg': 704.0, 'CO2_CEL_SE_I_001-Avg': 1184.0}
```

**chosenSensors = ["CO2_BUR_NE_I_001"]**

```
{'_id': {'year': 2016}, 'CO2_BUR_NE_I_001-Count': 4, 'CO2_BUR_NE_I_001-Sum': 3520, 'CO2_BUR_NE_I_001-Avg': 880.0}
```

**chosenSensors = ["CO2_CEL_SE_I_001"]**

```
{'_id': {'year': 2016}, 'CO2_CEL_SE_I_001-Count': 5, 'CO2_CEL_SE_I_001-Sum': 5920, 'CO2_CEL_SE_I_001-Avg': 1184.0}
```

The behavior of the query is strange. When I define an array of multiple elements in chosenSensor it seems that the count of each field is the result of the count of the last field. When the defined array is compounded of a single element the count is correct.

Comment: You need to provide "small" sample here. Like 6 documents that show two keys appearing twice within those documents and that the count obtained is clearly only being obtained from one of those documents. Throwing large numbers at people is not something we can debug or see conclusively that your claim is correct. That's what I mean by a verifiable case.

Comment: @NeilLunn Edited. I hope that was what you expected (I'm not comfortable with English)

Comment: Isn't the 5 documents provided at the beginning enough? I created a collection with them and I reproduced the issue with the code I gave in this topic.

Comment: Sorry. Missed them. Didn't scroll up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misinterpreted the code I gave you in your own translation.

So this:

```
group['$group'][chosenSensor+'-Count'] =
  {'$sum':{'$cond':[{'$ifNull':[True, False]}, 1, 0]}}
```

Should be:

```
group['$group'][chosenSensor+'-Count'] = {
  {'$sum':{'$cond':[{'$ifNull':['$'+chosenSensor, False]}, 1, 0]}
```

Because with what you wrote you are asking `$ifNull` to evaluate the boolean of `True` which always exists, as opposed to the correct expression which should be the current "field", which we need to test if it exists.

So what was happening is that the fields were "always" being counted, which of course is the "average" problem we were trying to avoid.