# Avoid repeating stages of a Mongodb aggregation in sucesives queries

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using the mongodb aggregation framework to group documents using differents fields, repeating this query (just changing the group _id for each case).

```
collection.aggregate([
{'$match'  : {'attr1': {'$in': list_of_values}}},
{'$project': {
    'attr1'    : '$attr1',
    'strict': {'$cond':[{'$eq': [{'$size': {'$setDifference': ['$nocomp', '$exceps']}}, 0]}, 1, 0]},
    'score' : {'$divide': [
        {'$subtract': [{'$size': '$controls'}, {'$size': {'$setDifference': ['$nocomp', '$exceps']}}]},
        {'$size': '$controls'}
    ]}
}},
{'$lookup': {'from': 'another', 'localField': 'attr1', 'foreignField': '_id', 'as': 'attr1doc'}},
{'$unwind': '$attr1doc'},
{'$group' : {'_id': '$attr1doc.type', 'avg_score': {'$avg': '$score'}, 'avg_strict': {'$avg': '$strict'}, 'count': {'$sum': 1}}},
{'$unwind': '$_id'}
```

])

The result are documents in this form:

```
{
 '_id': 'some_value',
 'avg_score': 0.6,
 'avg_strict': 0.4
 }
```

Now, I'm repeating the operation multime times but using differents fields of 'attr1doc' to group the documents instead of 'attr1doc.type'.
Is there a way to avoid repeating the first stages of the pipeline each time since the result will be the same (assuming the collection does not change)?

Comment: Perhaps you mean `'$field1'`? Because as it stands that "literal string" is effectively equivalent to `null`, and really would make no difference if you changed it or not. For that reason and a complete lack of explanation for what actually needs to be achieved your question is extremely unclear. Best to show a working and reproducible case, with an expected result that is actually possible from the data presented.

Comment: Essentially, all the best parts of ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I hope now it's easier to understand what I'm asking.

Comment: Much clearer. You are asking something essentially similar to [this question and response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44717982/2313887)

Comment: Just in case: if you do not have performance issues, do any other thing more important than optimization ;)

Comment: @dgiugg Thanks for the advise :P but actually it is kind of slow how I do it.

Comment: @NeilLunn If I'm not mistaken your answer helps to avoid repeating part of the query in the code itself, what I am looking for is a way to tell the database "hey this part of the query is going to be the same so don't do that again". 
Maybe I need to save the documents before the $group stage on another collection in order to group them without actually doing the $match, $project and $lookup again.